# Spark compare two different datafames with different schema row by row

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates, compare

I am trying to identify duplicate rows between random dataframes

I will not know what columns are duplicated since they might have different columns names

```
df1 with columns a, b, c
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,1,1,1,1]
c = [5,6,7,8,9]

df2 with columns x, y, z
x = [1,2,3,5,6]
y= [1,1,1,1,1]
z = [8,9,10,1,11,]

we can tell the match rate table as

df1 df2 match rate
a    x   80%
b    y   100 %
c    z   20%
```

and the codes should check a with x, y, z
b with x, y, z, ...etc.

the result is expected as a new dataframe
with column names from 2 joined dfs and their match rate

I did try different ways using plain joins and intersect but nothing close, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

does your df1 and df2 have the same key like row_number?
if yes, you could join them together use:

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2, "key")
```

after the join, you could use [vectorassembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler) to make array of (a,b,c) called left_array, and could make array of (x,y,z) called right array

after the array, use [array intersect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect)
to get the intersect of two field, then dived the length gets you the overlap percentage.

Comment: Sorry for being late on this @E.ZY. but my df1 and df2 dont have a key.

Comment: Do you want to check column a df1 with every single column x,y,z in the df2? or just column a vs column x, column b vs column y . 

I misunderstood your question because you are checking the column-wise  comparsion instead of row-wise, you don't need to join them together.
instead df_combined = df1.withColumn("x", df2.x) will append df2's x column to your df1,